# 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position XX

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple script that is attempting to extract mutiple json objects from a single file, and store it as a list:

```
import json

URL = r"C:\Users\Kenneth\Youtube_comment_parser\Testing.txt"

with open(URL, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as handle:
    json_data = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]

print(json_data) # Can't .encode() because it's a list
```

Even after specifying utf-8 encoding, I'm still running into a codec error. If possible, I would also like to change this object into a dictionary, but this is as far as I've got.

The exact error reads:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position
394-395: character maps to <undefined>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by removing one unicode character that was producing "/undefined>", the string '\ufeff', and then the rest was able to display nicely. This required me to iterate over the keys in the list of dictionaries, and replace as necessary.

```
import json

URL = r"C:\Users\Kenneth\Youtube_comment_parser\Testing.txt"

json1_file = open(URL, encoding='utf-8')
json1_str = json1_file.read()
json1_str = [d.strip() for d in json1_str.splitlines()]
json1_data = [json.loads(i) for i in json1_str]

json1_data = [{key:value.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for
              key, value in json1_data[index].items()} for
              index in range(len(json1_data))]

print(json1_data[1]['text'].encode('utf-8'))
```

Still not sure why I have to open with utf-8 and then encode again with my print statement, but it produced the string nicely.